# jQUERY - возврат после remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать возврат после remove текста?

```
    <head>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("td").remove(".diffUnmodified");
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<td class="diffUnmodified">ТЕКСТ</td>
    <button>Удалить</button>
    </body>
```

Comment: хочешь возвратить удаленный кусок `html`?

Comment: Да все верно вернуть кусок

Comment: так зачем удалить? можете скрыть `display: none;`